# Poor object detection with OpenCV DNN and YOLOv3

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

OpenCV comes with [object detection sample code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/object_detection.py) for its DNN module.

I downloaded the [YOLOv3](https://pjreddie.com/yolo/) model and a sample image from the same COCO dataset it was trained on:

```
wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights  
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pjreddie/darknet/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg
wget http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7272/7745390240_0dcf7d107d_z.jpg
```

Here are the objects that are labeled in the scene:

[image: labeled objects]

Then I ran the sample code to detect objects in the unlabeled image:

```
python object_detection.py --model yolov3.weights --config yolov3.cfg --height 320 --input 7745390240_0dcf7d107d_z.jpg
```

This draws rectangles around the objects it detects. But the detections are basically garbage.

[image: detections]

---

If I just use Darknet directly, here is what it labels:

[image: darknet output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The missing parameters seem to be `--scale 0.00392 --rgb` which come from [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d9d/tutorial_dnn_yolo.html).

```
  --scale SCALE         Preprocess input image by multiplying on a scale
                        factor. (default: 1.0)
  --rgb                 Indicate that model works with RGB input images
                        instead BGR ones. (default: False)
```

These are passed as parameters to `cv2.dnn.blobFromImage`.

I think `scale` is not actually resizing the input image but converting each element of the image to a float in the [0.0, 1.0] range. 0.00392 is approximately 1/255.